# Error while returning nominal value in case where value is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Block of code below works perfectly for the most part. The issue is that I'm trying to "inject" a nominal value for a particular row of no value exists for that row...

```
  DECLARE @ReportTimeStart DATETIME = '2019-05-10 06:59:00'
  DECLARE @ReportTimeEnd DATETIME = '2019-05-10 23:01:00'
  ;

  --The "WITH" block returns a list of the total time spent in the state for each event in the list from the sub-query
  WITH StateTimes AS
  (
    SELECT
        [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
        [Machine_State],
        DATEDIFF(second, [t_stamp], NextStateTime) AS TimeInState
    FROM
      (
      --This sub-query block ("SQ") returns a list of start and end times for each event. NULL value in the last recrd is replaced with the report end time.
      SELECT
            [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx],
            [Machine_State],
            [t_stamp],
            ISNULL(LEAD([t_stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [tbl_tg_machinestate_ndx]), @ReportTimeEnd) NextStateTime
      FROM [db_SPE_Carrig].[dbo].[tbl_TG_MachineState]
      WHERE [t_stamp] BETWEEN @ReportTimeStart AND @ReportTimeEnd
      ) SQ
  )

  --This final query returns an aggregated list of total time spent in each state over the report duration
  SELECT
    [Machine_State],

    CASE WHEN SUM(TimeInState) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(TimeInState) END AS [CumulativeTimeSec],

    CumulativeTime = CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(TimeInState), 0), 108)

  FROM
    StateTimes
  GROUP BY
    [Machine_State]
  ORDER BY
    [Machine_State]
```

The inner query in the WITH block produces data looking like this:

```
_ndx            Machine_State   t_stamp                 NextStateTime
10211           170             2019-05-10 07:03:46.883 2019-05-10 07:03:48.087
10212           110             2019-05-10 07:03:48.087 2019-05-10 07:04:02.123
10213           120             2019-05-10 07:04:02.123 2019-05-10 07:04:07.333
```

The whole WITH block produces a table like this:

```
_ndx    Machine_State   TimeInState
10211   170             2
10212   110             14
10213   120             5
10214   130             20
```

Each instance of each different state have the time difference calculated.

Last step is to aggregate this table and sum up all instances of each state like so:

```
Machine_State   CumulativeTimeSec   CumulativeTime  Description
100             6728                01:52:08        Safeties Down
110             464                 00:07:44        Initialising
120             93                  00:01:33        Ready to Start
130             14986               04:09:46        Running
140             1405                00:23:25        Dwell
150             161                 00:02:41        Stopped
170             33597               09:19:57        Faulted
```

Problem is, I have no instance for state 160: Okay because there actually isn't one but this causes problems with a report.

**In this scenario, all I want to do is create a nominal value for state=160 of 1sec.**

I thought the CASE statement would achieve this but of course there is no instance of state=160 for the CASE statement to capture...

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression? `CASE WHEN {expr} = 0 THEN 1 ELSE {expr} END` or a `NULLIF`, `ISNULL`? `ISNULL(NULLIF({expr},0),1)`? Sample data, and expected result, would make this far easier to understand.

Comment: I do not think so that the problem is with the CASE part. Your CASE statement is fine. The problem is with 'CumulativeTime'. You have to put the column in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Re-Write the case as a sum itself `SUM(CASE WHEN TimeInState < 1 THEN 1 ELSE TimeInState END) AS CumulativeTimeSec`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Can't believe I missed that. That corrected the error but I still haven't solved my problem. Will edit the port to re-clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The commas in your select list won't work.

```
CASE WHEN SUM(TimeInState) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(TimeInState) END AS [CumulativeTimeSec] --Comma missing
CumulativeTime = CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(TimeInState), 0), 108), -- extra Comma
```

Swapping the lines around should work.

Comment: Yes, saw that thanks. Have edited the question accordingly.